# Updating main ui after all loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

The problem is as follows, it executes another form but uses the primary so the program becomes "unavailable".

I tried with backgroundworker but after found out this method and switched.

```cs
 private async void Disp_data_Sim()
        {
            var windowToOpen = new WaitingWorker()
            {
                Owner = this,
            };

            await Task.Run(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {

                    windowToOpen.ShowDialog();
                });
                try
                {
                    var tempCon = File.ReadAllText("DBConnection.json");
                    var tempCon1 = Crypt.Decrypt(tempCon, "encryption");
                    var sqlInfo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<SQLInfo>(tempCon1);
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlInfo.GetConString()))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT referencia,descricao,pr_custo1,etiqueta,qtd FROM Etiquetas Where etiqueta = @etiqueta";
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@etiqueta", 'S');
                            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            da.Fill(dtbl);

                            dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.DataSource = dtbl));
                        }
                        con.Close();

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {

                    windowToOpen.Close();
                });
            }));
        }
```

What I am trying to do is, I need to open another form in another thread where there is a progress bar that is indeterminated, and in main ui I need to update the datagrid with the bd data after the load is gone.

Comment: *I need to open another form in another thread* Why do you believe you need to do this? That is generally a really bad idea. There is one and only one UI thread.

Comment: Because there is to much data on db and i need to load it all and if dont do a waiting form it will break the program and it will not respond for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid mixing UI and non-UI code.

Try this:

```
private async void Disp_data_Sim()
{
    var windowToOpen = new WaitingWorker()
    {
        Owner = this,
    };

        try
        {
            windowToOpen.ShowDialog();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = await GetDataAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        windowToOpen.Close();
}

private async Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync()
{
    var tempCon = File.ReadAllText("DBConnection.json");
    var tempCon1 = Crypt.Decrypt(tempCon, "encryption");
    var sqlInfo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<SQLInfo>(tempCon1);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlInfo.GetConString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT referencia,descricao,pr_custo1,etiqueta,qtd FROM Etiquetas Where etiqueta = @etiqueta";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@etiqueta", 'S');
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                await con.OpenAsync();
                await Task.Yield(); // just to make sure it yields back to the caller.
                da.Fill(dtbl);
                return dtbl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `SqlDataAdapter` does not have an asynchronous API. You could make this better by using a `SqlDataReader` and filling the table yourself.